# MongoDB shell: How to convert array fields into string

Tags: mongodb

I have a collection which stores values as arrays, but these need to be strings.

Out of 4000 data sets 800 look like this

```
{'_id': '5c4f8408fc69ca02c92ac822',
 'enabled': true,
 'order_date': '2019-01-29T10:36:56.906Z',
 'order_id': 'PO-ERSNJ9',
 'productId': ['5dd5ca0170ebec13b8ab1134'],
 'selling_date': null,
 'selling_price': 99.99,
 'split_invoice': null}
```

for these 800 I need to convert
`"productId" : [ "5dd5ca0170ebec13b8ab1134" ]`
into
`"productId" : "5dd5ca0170ebec13b8ab1134"`
via mongo shell.

I already figured, that `reduce` (aggregation) would be the way to go,
but I cannot get the syntax right.

Help would be great. Thanks a lot

Comment: Here is a similar question with some answers: [convert string array to string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58850390/how-to-convert-string-array-to-string-by-keeping-the-contents-of-array-as-comma/58854166#58854166).

Answer (score 7):

This shell query updates the collection with the string value of the "orderId" array field.

```
db.orders.aggregate( [
  { 
     $match: { productId: { $type: "array" } } 
  },
  { 
     $addFields: { productId: { $arrayElemAt: [ "$productId", 0 ] } } 
  }
] 
).forEach( doc => db.orders.updateOne( { _id: doc._id }, { $set: { productId: doc.productId } } ) );
```

---

This update will work to convert the array value to a string - this works with **MongoDB 4.2** or later versions only. Note the update uses an *Aggregation pipeline within* the `update` method.

```
db.orders.updateMany( 
  { 
      productId: { $type: "array" } 
  },
  [
      { 
          $set: { productId: { $arrayElemAt: [ "$productId", 0 ] } } 
      },
  ]
)
```

Comment: MongoDB v 4.4 introduces the [$first](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/first-array-element/) array aggregate operator. In the above `updateMany` it can be used as `productId: { $first: "$productId" }`  _instead of_ `productId: { $arrayElemAt: [ "$productId", 0 ] }`.

Answer (score 1):

the [mongodb `$unwind` operator](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) should do what you want. See an example in the MongoDB shell below.

```
> use test
switched to db test
> db.stack.insertOne({ "_id" : "5c4f8408fc69ca02c92ac822", "enabled" : true, "productId" : [ "5dd5ca0170ebec13b8ab1134" ], "selling_price" : 99.99, "order_date" : "2019-01-29T10:36:56.906Z", "order_id" : "PO-ERSNJ9", "selling_date" : null, "split_invoice" : null })
{ "acknowledged" : true, "insertedId" : "5c4f8408fc69ca02c92ac822" }
> db.stack.aggregate( [{"$unwind" : "$productId"}])
{ "_id" : "5c4f8408fc69ca02c92ac822", "enabled" : true, "productId" : "5dd5ca0170ebec13b8ab1134", "selling_price" : 99.99, "order_date" : "2019-01-29T10:36:56.906Z", "order_id" : "PO-ERSNJ9", "selling_date" : null, "split_invoice" : null }
>
```